# N-Dimensional Matrix Array in Python (with different sizes)

Tags: python, matrix

In Matlab, there is something called struct, which allow the user to have a dynamic set of matrices.

I'm basically looking for a function that allows me to index over dynamic matrices that have different sizes.

Example: (with 3 matrices)

- Matrix 1: 3x2
- Matrix 2: 2x2
- Matrix 3: 2x1

Basically I want to store the 3 matrices on the same variable. To called them by their index number afterward (i.e. Matrix[1], Matrx[2]). Conventional python arrays do not allow for arrays with different dimensions to be stacked.

I was looking into creating classes, but maybe someone her has a better alternative to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a tuple or list.

A tuple `matrices = tuple(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3)` will be slightly more efficient;

A list `matrices = [matrix1, matrix2, matrix3]` is more flexible as you can `matrix.append(matrix4)`.

Either way you can access them as `matrices[0]` or `for matrix in matricies: pass # do stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

Put those arrays into a **list**.